# Powershell script runs fine on one computer but errors out on another

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script that calls a C# exe file that works no problem on my machine and a couple other machines on our network, but for some reason it won't run on the computer it needs to. This is the error I get when I try and run it. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

It will run no problem on a couple other machines on the same network no problem, just not on this particular one. Any input would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Your C# application was built for Win64 and you're trying to run it on a Win32 version of the OS. 64-bit applications cannot run on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: Gotcha. So for it to work on that machine I'm gonna have to write a new version of the C# program?

Comment: No. Compile the same C# program with `AnyCPU` as the target (or compile it as 32-bit, which will work on both 32 and 64 bit versions of the OS).

Comment: I am running this in Visual Studio, how would I do that in there? or do I have to do it through command prompt?

Comment: Project->Properties->Build->Platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your C# application was compiled as 64-bit, and you're trying to run it on a system with Windows 32-bit. 64-bit applications will not run on 32-bit operating systems.

Rebuild the C# application with either *AnyCPU* or *Win32* as the target platform. You can do this through the *Project* menu; edit the properties of your application, go to the *Build* page, and change the *Platform* in the drop-down list at the top of that page, and then build your project.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be sure, but I think your app is 64bit compiled, and you're trying to run it on a 32bit machine.